# Can some people beat roulette wheels using "visual ballistics"?

Tags: physics, technology, gambling

In the past, people beat roulette wheels using machines that measure ball speed and predict where the ball will land. That is discussed in the question [Is it possible to gain an edge in roulette through physics?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14193/is-it-possible-to-gain-an-edge-in-roulette-through-physics).
However, nowadays such machines are forbidden to use.

With [visual ballistics](https://www.roulettesystems.com/professional/visual-ballistics), people try to simulate such machines with only their eyes and mental calculations.

> One of the systems you can use to play roulette based on the laws of physics is visual ballistics. For this you use your own eyes to be able to predict where the ball will land. You note at what number the ball bounces off one of the surrounding diamonds and where the ball then lands. Then you count the number of spaces in between these two points and keep written records of the results. After about 60 to 100 spins you have already collected enough data to be able to deduct something useful and also to note any remarkable outcomes.
>
> [...]
>
> Unfortunately, you're already too late to bet at that stage, so you really also need to know when the ball only a few spins left to go. Then you observe what number is located under the diamond and where the ball eventually ends up. You also record this to know how many spaces there are between these two slots.

According to another site ([Roulette Physics](https://www.roulettephysics.com/visual-ballistics-roulette-prediction-methods/)), some wheels can be beaten (i.e. a positive expected return) using visual ballistics. Is this true?

To clarify, I’m not asking about other methods than Visual Ballistics.

A potential example of someone who used visual ballistics effectively, is [Niko Tosa](https://www.bloomberg.com/features/2023-how-to-beat-roulette-gambler-figures-it-out/). He made millions of dollars playing Roulette. Casino employees and police have never found a prediction device on him.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148111/discussion-on-question-by-riemann-can-you-beat-some-roulette-wheels-using-visua); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.